# LINQ group by query help: Select another related table with key

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Please help me complete the following query:

```
var results = from species in db.Species
              join cats in db.Categories on species.CategoryId equals cats.CategoryId
              join groups in db.Groups on cats.GroupId equals groups.GroupId
              group groups by groups into g
              select new GroupWithCategoryChildren
              {
                  Group = g.Key,
                  Categories = (cats from above query for this same g.Key group)???
              };
```

I could do this really easily with SQL, but I'm struggling with LINQ. I want to end up with a List of each `Group` ALONG WITH the `cats` that joined to it in the above/main single query, ideally without re-querying for that data again in a separate query.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you post how you would do it in SQL? That will tell us what you need, and a LINQ expert can easily translate for you.

Comment: You can use subqueries in LINQ, but as Shannon mentioned, without seeing your SQL or how all of those tables are supposed to relate to each other there is no way to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry guys, I realise I didn't provide the best explanation in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood correctly but I think this is all you need: Instead of `group groups by groups` do `group cats by groups` and then the `Key` will be the `groups` and the values of the group will be all the matching categories.

```
var results = from species in db.Species
              join cats in db.Categories on species.CategoryId equals cats.CategoryId
              join groups in db.Groups on cats.GroupId equals groups.GroupId
              group cats by groups into g
              select new GroupWithCategoryChildren
              {
                  Group = g.Key,
                  Categories = g.ToList()
              };
```

I used this to test it:

```
List<dynamic> Species = new List<dynamic>()
{
    new { A = "1", CategoryId = 1 },
    new { A = "2", CategoryId = 2 },
};

List<dynamic> Categories = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { B = "1", CategoryId = 1, GroupId = 1 },
    new { B = "2", CategoryId = 2, GroupId = 1 },
};

List<dynamic> Groups = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { C = "1", GroupId = 1 }
};

//result: { Group: { C = "1", GroupId = 1 }, Categories (1,2)}
```

Comment: Hi Gilad, a huge thanks. Yep this was exactly what I needed. I ended up implementing a slightly varied version of this (as I needed to also go another 2nd level deep), but it's based on exactly your example solution shown above. Many thanks for your help.